# Database design for Instagram-like post/comments

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'd like a review of my design for an Instagram-like application where users can post and comment on pictures.

I just finished a freecodecamp crash course on database design and this is the first ERD I make. If you also have suggestions for readings on this topic I'd appreciate it.

[image]

This is my SQL code:

````
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    salted_password TEXT NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE photos
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    caption VARCHAR(150),
    latitude DECIMAL,
    longitude DECIMAL,
    src TEXT NOT NULL,
    size INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE avatars
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    src TEXT NOT NULL,
    size INTEGER NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE comments
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    photo_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    comment VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(photo_id) REFERENCES photos(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```
````